# C fwrite writes extra zeros

Tags: c

when i read from the result.bin file it puts the value i want then fill with 3 zeros then next value and so on i cant figure out why tried diffrent compilers (minigw cygwin and msdn) same result on all.
also tried reading it in matlab and using the functions in the libraries stdio,stdlib

first sorry for the bad posting i was in a hurry here is a better hopfully more clear description:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {
    int output[4];
    int k=0;

    output[0]=1;
    output[1]=11;
    output[2]=2;
    output[3]=22;

    FILE *result;
    result=fopen("C:/Users/Mattias/Desktop/result.bin","w+b");
    fwrite(output,sizeof(int),4,result);
                        printf("%d\n", output[0]);
                        printf("%d\n", output[1]);
                        printf("%d\n", output[2]);
                        printf("%d\n", output[3]);

    fclose(result);


    result=fopen("C:/Users/Mattias/Desktop/result.bin","r+b");
    printf("%s\n", "whats written to result");

        int buffer1[3];
        long int size = sizeof(buffer1);

    if (!result)
    {
            printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }
    for ( k=0; k <= 3; k++)
    {
            buffer1[k]=fgetc(result); 
            printf("%d\n", buffer1[k]);
    }
        fclose(result);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and the output i get from reading the result.bin file is:

1
0
0
0
11
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
22
0
0
0
and what i want to get when i read is just 1 11 2 22
Thanks for the help
ps. i used a 1 in fwrite becouse i know the data iam handeling is only 1 byte big

Comment: 1) You don't `fclose()` the file. (And don't check the `fopen()` for success.) 2) Please add the precise observed result, expected result. As-is, it is a bit hard to tell what exactly is baffling you.

Comment: fwrite works with bytes, not integers. `int`s are usually 4 bytes. When you pass 1 and 4 to `fwrite`, that is telling it to write 4 elements of 1 byte each (starting at the first element of `output`). So really, you're just writing the first integer in the array.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you expect to see in the `result.bin` file

Comment: @DevSolar files are automatically closed when the program returns from `main`

Comment: You need to pass sizeof(int), not 1.

Comment: @M.M: Yes, but other handles, like e.g. memory, might not be. Releasing allocated resources before you go out of scope is good coding practice. Neither an `fclose()` nor a check of the `fopen()` return value fixes the OP's problem, but he might become a better coder for it.

Comment: See @Cameron's comment. Either use `sizeof(int)` as the second argument of `fwrite` (and then you get 16 bytes, all of which are 0-padded bytes essentially, in little endian order on a Windows Intel system, or use output as a `unsigned char` array and use 1 as the second argument and get 4 bytes, no padding.

Comment: or! even better, use `<stdint.h>` and more standardized types: `int8 int16 int32 uint8 uint16 uint32` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int output[57];
    int k=0;

    output[0]=1;
    output[1]=11;
    output[2]=2;
    output[3]=22;

    FILE *result;
    result=fopen("C:/Users/ael09mol/Desktop/data/result.bin","w+b");
    fwrite(output,sizeof(int),4,result);

                        printf("%d\n", output[0]);
                        printf("%d\n", output[1]);
                        printf("%d\n", output[2]);
                        printf("%d\n", output[3]);
    fclose(result);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

fwrite function: second parameter should contain the size of the object to copy, in bytes.

> Following is the declaration for fwrite() function.
>
> size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE
>   *stream)
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> ptr − This is the pointer to the array of elements to be written.
>
> size − This is the size in bytes of each element to be written.
>
> nmemb − This is the number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
>
> stream − This is the pointer to a FILE object that specifies an output stream.
> ```